# Adding and removing from a has_many :through relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, many-to-many, has-many-through

From the Rails associations guide, they demonstrate a many-to-many relationship using has_many :through like so:

```
class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, :through => :appointments
end

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, :through => :appointments
end
```

How would I create and remove appointments?

If I've got a `@physician`, do I write something like the following for creating an appointment?

```
@patient = @physician.patients.new params[:patient]
@physician.patients << @patient
@patient.save # Is this line needed?
```

What about code for deleting or destroying? Also, if a Patient no longer existed in the Appointment table will it get destroyed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your code of creating an appointment, the second line is not needed, and using `#build` method instead of `#new`:

```
@patient = @physician.patients.build params[:patient]
@patient.save  # yes, it worked
```

For destroying an appointment record you could simply find it out and destroy:

```
@appo = @physician.appointments.find(1)
@appo.destroy
```

If you want to destroy the appointment records along with destroying a patient, you need to add the :dependency setting to has_many:

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, :through => :appointments, :dependency => :destroy
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I assume that deleting the appointment will also remove the physician from the patient and vice versa?

Comment: No, it won't unless you add `:dependency => :destroy` to `belongs_to`.

Comment: Actually the `:dependency` setting simply add a before_destroy hook to the model. Without this no other model would be affected when destroying a model record.